# (AS3) Functions

Tags: actionscript-3

I managed to fix the whole null stage error by following MJW's guide on debugging Error #1009. But now the function that initializes the bullets doesn't get called.

Snippets:

```
if (stage) {
 init();
} else {
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);               
}
```

...

```
private function init(event:Event = null) {

    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, shoot);


}
```

...

```
private function shoot(event:Event) {

    var bullet:EnemyBullet = new EnemyBullet();

    stage.addChild(bullet);

    bullet.x = enemy.x;
    bullet.y = enemy.y;

    bullet.theta = Math.random() * 360;

    bManager.bulletVector.push(bullet);


}
```

Note that when I put trace() within the second two functions, nothing happens, but the addEventListener() in the first snippet does get called (or so I think).

Comment: 1) Are you sure the first snippet is being called? Throw a breakpoint/trace in there to verify. 2) Is the object actually being added to the stage? Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE is only called when the object is added to the stage (makes sense, right?) so if you aren't actually adding it to the stage, it will **never** be called

Comment: can you paste your whole class?

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3 I did do a trace test, which is how I verified that it's being called. So what should I use instead? I get an error when I stick the code within the shoot function where the first snippet is.

Comment: You never answered my second question: Are you adding this to the stage? If you are not, then `stage` will *always* be null and Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE will *never* be dispatched.

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3 Sorry, I am adding the object to the stage. How do I go about initializing it?

Comment: If you are actually adding it to the stage, we need more information because that event should be firing. Could you please show us the code where you are adding the item to the stage (if it is not `stage.addChild(bullet)`)?

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3 It should be stage.addChild(bullet).

Comment: So the line that adds the code to the stage is only called by a stage event listener which isn't added until that item is on the stage? That would probably be your problem right there. The logic behind that process is completely incorrect.

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3 Okay, wow, this is pretty confusing. How do I go about fixing it?

Comment: By rethinking the logic. Basically your code is dependent on its own dependencies. For Thing 1 to happen, Thing 2 has to happen. But for Thing 2 to happen, Thing 1 has to happen. Do you see the enclosed cycle in that logic? Neither is possible without the other happening, so neither is possible. I'm unsure how you would fix it, but I am fairly certain that is your problem.

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3 That's really weird, especially since it works with my other class that uses bullets.

Comment: Are you sure its stage that is null? to me it looks like bManager.bulletVector isn't defined anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general practice, `stage` [should not be referenced](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild%28%29) - especially in your case, where your reference is solely to add instances of your bullet class.  If it's a matter of z-index, you could instead have a layer in which bullets are placed on top of other display objects on the display list.

Besides complexities loading multiple SWFs on a single stage, your code would become nice isolated functional units by adding display objects to their own hierarchy of the display list.  Or, you could leverage a MVC pattern whereby a controller manipulated views.

In order for your code to work, that class must either be the main function of the SWF or added to stage.

If it's the main function of the SWF, `init()` will be called.

Otherwise, assure it's getting added to the display list via an `addChild()`.

Do you really intend to fire a bullet every frame?  That could be 24 to 60 bullets a second.  You might want to throttle that with some probability whether a bullet with fire.

Say this was a battlefield, and your battlefield class was added to stage, it could be implemented as this:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    [SWF(percentWidth = 100, percentHeight = 100, backgroundColor = 0x0, frameRate = 30)]
    public class Battlefield extends Sprite
    {
        public function Battlefield()
        {
            if (stage)
                init();
            else
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
        }

        protected function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
            init();
        }
        protected function init():void
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameHandler);
        }

        protected function frameHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            var odds:Number = Math.random();

            trace((odds < 0.1 ? "Fire!   " : "Skip...") + "Odds were: " + odds);
        }

    }
}
```

Which would output:

```
Skip... Odds were: 0.3539872486144304
Skip... Odds were: 0.742108017206192
Fire!   Odds were: 0.025597115512937307
Skip... Odds were: 0.7608889108523726
Fire!   Odds were: 0.08514392375946045 
Skip... Odds were: 0.27881692815572023
```

Beyond Stage3D, I've never been fond of this initialization pattern, as you could just as easily rely on stage events, as in:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    [SWF(percentWidth = 100, percentHeight = 100, backgroundColor = 0x0, frameRate = 30)]
    public class Battlefield extends Sprite
    {
        public function Battlefield()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
        }

        protected function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
            addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removedFromStageHandler);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameHandler);
        }

        protected function removedFromStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameHandler);

            removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removedFromStageHandler);
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
        }

        protected function frameHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            var odds:Number = Math.random();

            trace((odds < 0.1 ? "Fire!   " : "Skip...") + "Odds were: " + odds);
        }

    }
}
```

Therefore, upon added to stage the class initiates its actions, and upon removed from stage the class terminates its actions.

Comment: Great examples, but the bullets are still not initializing for some reason.

Comment: Bullets would have their own initialization.  In this scope, such as a `Battlefield`, there must be a control outside the scope of the bullet that fires the bullets.

Comment: Oh wow, I feel pretty stupid forgetting that. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the first block.

you are checking for stage, if stage is not null, then use a added to stage listener.

you should only be using `addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);`

however, this is assuming that the class is DisplayObject subclass, objects that do not get added to stage cannot call the ADDED_TO_STAGE listener

Comment: No, he is actually doing that right. If it hasn't already been added to the stage, add the listener. If it has been added to the stage, fire the method manually. It is likely redundant (my guess is the function that is in occurs before the parent is added to the stage), but it is a good habit to get into.